# The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: eclipse, maven

Hi get the following error when compiling and deploying using STS 3.6 (spring eclipse)

```
17/10/2014 3:24:22 pm AEDT: [WARN] The POM for au.gov.nsw.lands:spring-common:jar:0.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available
17/10/2014 3:24:22 pm AEDT: [WARN] The POM for gov.lpi.six:WcmUtils:jar:0.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
17/10/2014 3:24:22 pm AEDT: [WARN] The POM for com.exadel:htmLib:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

POM exists in the repository and are valid as I am able to compile and deploy using STS 3.2/maven 3.0.2. I

Any ideas on how to over come.

Comment: `mvn -X` and make sure you use the same Maven instance/config.

Comment: First check if your build works on command line and check the output if there are no network errors etc. cause this look like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your setting.xml and repository path
2. Check your windows > preferences > maven > setting (check correct repo path mentioned)
3. Also check that proper artifact, group id and version is mentioned in POM.xml
4. Check the respective folder path for those dependencies which are not downloaded.

   - Delete the respective folder
   - Try again with maven > update dependency in eclipse