# The POM for ... is missing, no d ependency information available in Spring Boot Maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have added local jar using mvn install:install file as below:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile='D:\WS\APP_Latest\app\lib\Services.jar' -DgroupId=Services -DartifactId=Services -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

then added dependency in pom.xml as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>Services</groupId>
    <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then trying to build entire application and getting warning message as below:

```
[WARNING] The POM for ...:jar:1.0 is missing, no d
ependency information available
```

But i am able to see added jar in maven dependencies and also in path "C:\Users...m2....pom".

Can any one please suggest on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476246/the-pom-for-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available)

Comment: That solution not resolving my issue please try to suggest on my issue.Thanks @htshame

Comment: can you please show full  pom.xml code